# Regex pattern to detect a link but not an image

Tags: php, regex, url

I've been fooling around for a while with regex. A few days ago I started modifying a regex pattern I found some time ago. It detects all hyperlinks, my version should only detect hyperlinks and not images.

```
http://domain.com/someimage.jpg
```

shouldn't be detected. But it does detect an image partly. I don't how to solve this.

The original regex:

```
/(https?)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,10}(\/\S*)?/i
```

Link to my version:

http://regexr.com/38rv9

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: What if the image isn't recognizable as such (through mod_rewrite or similar)?

Comment: The idea is that a user can paste a link from the url bar. Pasting an unrecongnizable image won't be a big problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a space at last.

```
/((https?)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,10}(\/(?:(\S(?!jpg|jpeg|png|gif))*))?)\s/ig
```

Comment: np. you could shorten it maybe like this. /((https?)\S(\/(?:(\S(?!jpg|jpeg|png|gif))*))?)\s/ig . But if it works, so its okey :)

Answer (score 0):

I would accomplish this by making sure what is clicked by the user does NOT end with an image file extension. You mention you are using php; have ONE condition statement that matches your original regex:

```
/(https?)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,10}(\/\S*)?/i
```

but does not match any common image file extension at the END of the expression:

```
/^.*\.*[*(jpg$|jpeg$|gif$|png$|tif$)]/i
```

This would work for any text string that precedes the image file extension; `preg_match` will be useful to accomplish this.